# How to set a fixed width and height in jfree chart in excel

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to set a fixed width and height to all charts in the generated excel document but when column width of the sheet get different, the chart width also varies according to column width. How can I resolve this? I used the following method to set a fixed size but it doesn't work. Find the [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p731S.jpg) attached.

```
int width = 150;
int height = 350;

ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(chartOutOne, quality, pie1, width, height);
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(chartOutTwo, quality, pie2, width, height);
```

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: @trashgod I think this question is about apache-poi. Seems the user asked the question with a misleading title

Comment: @IsuruPathirana: Thanks for commenting; reopened.